# Not working android push notification through cron job

Tags: push-notification, push

We have a web application in PHP through which we sent events android push notification to users on our app.On web we have provided a select,after what time do they need alert 15min,30min for that event.A alert push notification is to be send on the device before 15 and 30 min start of the event.We have a corn job which sends a push notification to be send on the device before 15 and 30 min start of the event

Problem area:
We our getting a  push notification when we post it but we are not getting notification for the alerts.Corn job working fine. We our receiving success response from the Google.But not receiving notification on phone

can any one suggest what else need to be done on this.